# POST operation on /logout and getting No mapping for GET /login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to perform logout so I send POST on `/logout` but what I get is:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1590427554418,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/login"
}
```

I'm using POSTMAN. Despite having error logout perform correclly, because I cannot make any actions on other endpoints when I'm not logged.
The point is when code is uploaded on the server I got timeout:

[image]

I thought it might be somehow related.

**WebSecurityConfiguration**

```
package odd.jobs.configuration;

import odd.jobs.configuration.authentication.JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter;
import odd.jobs.configuration.authentication.RestAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import odd.jobs.configuration.authentication.RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import odd.jobs.services.user.UserCrudService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity()
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserCrudService userService;

    private final RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;

    private final RestAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfiguration(UserCrudService userService, RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler, RestAuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.authenticationSuccessHandler = authenticationSuccessHandler;
        this.authenticationFailureHandler = authenticationFailureHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))

                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .permitAll();
        http.cors();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter filter = new JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(super.authenticationManagerBean());
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("*")));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH")));
        // setAllowCredentials(true) is important, otherwise:
        // The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        // setAllowedHeaders is important! Without it, OPTIONS preflight request
        // will fail with 403 Invalid CORS request
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type")));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you used postman but with wrong method type as postman exception implies
Please change postman HTTP method from GET to POST from here :

[image]

Hope it should work!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use POST /logout, configure Spring Security with `new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "POST")` instead of `new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")` (GET is used by default)